Compiler doesn't issue warning on `uint64_t` under strict C89 mode
I'm trying to write strict ISO C89-compliant code. Since long long is not standard and is often implemented as compiler extensions before C99, the compiler should warn me it when I use it. However, when using either gcc or clang, there's no warning when int64_t is used and expands to long long (with 32-bit compilation -m32). Is there any way to make the compiler warn me?
For example:
/* test.c */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("The size of an int64_t is %u.\n", (unsigned)sizeof(int64_t));
    return 0;
}

Compiled with clang or gcc:
clang-17 -m32 -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors test.c
# or
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-13.2.1 -m32 -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors test.c

They issue no warning or error, even if the int64_t is actually a typedef to long long int, since clang-17 -m32 -std=c89 -E -dD -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors test.c gives me:
...
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long long int
#define __INT64_FMTd__ "lld"
#define __INT64_FMTi__ "lli"
#define __INT64_C_SUFFIX__ LL
...

and in /path/to/clang/17/include/stdint.h there's
...
#ifdef __INT64_TYPE__
# ifndef __int8_t_defined /* glibc sys/types.h also defines int64_t*/
typedef __INT64_TYPE__ int64_t;
# endif /* __int8_t_defined */
typedef __UINT64_TYPE__ uint64_t;
# undef __int_least64_t
...

But if I replace int64_t with long long or __INT64_TYPE__ in the above test.c the compiler will complain about it. So why there's a behavioral difference between long long and uint64_t?
The most relevant question on SO seems to be this and this, but their answers don't seem to explain why there's no warning when using -m32. (In -m64 mode uint64_t is not a problem since it expands to long, which is in C89 standard).
-- EDIT --
Eric's answer explained nicely why and how compilers treat system headers and user headers differently. For those who might be interested, in addition to creating your own sets of headers, I found one way to make the compiler also check C-standard compliance for system headers:

Use clang -v <args>... to generate the command that clang is actually running;
Replace all -internal-isystem with -I;
Run the modified command, then clang will output:

In file included from test.c:2:
/usr/lib/clang/17/include/stdint.h:10:1: error: // comments are not allowed in this language [-Werror,-Wcomment]
   10 | // AIX system headers need stdint.h to be re-enterable while _STD_TYPES_T
      | ^
/usr/lib/clang/17/include/stdint.h:52:3: error: #include_next is a language extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-include-next]
   52 | # include_next <stdint.h>
      |   ^
2 errors generated.

meaning that the standard library is not C89-compliant, which is the expected behavior.

C89 doesn't have stdint.h.

@interjay Yes I'm aware of that, but C89 doesn't prevent you from including the system or compiler's stdint.h or provide your own, which leads to this problem.

Standard int64_t isn't long long, it's int64_t.  What an implementation does internally to present a type to a user doesn't matter.  The use of -std=c89 and -pedantic IMO should result in a diagnostic, though, since int64_t is not a "standard type" in C89, so the long long would be an extension.  Given C89 is over a third of a century old, I suspect there might be some cobwebs along the code path you're making the compiler go down.

If you provide your own stdint.h then you'll get the same warning as when you use long long directly. If you use the system's stdint.h then you're already using compiler-specific extensions so I don't see how a warning would help.

For each standard header, make a file of the same name that starts with #define int64_t DoNotUseint64_t plus similar definitions for other types you want to avoid. Then add #include <absolute path to actual standard header>. Then add #undef int64_t. Put those files in a directory, and compile with -isystem ThatDirectory. (Note you must do this for each standard header, because standard headers are allowed to include and define others even if the C standard does not explicitly say so. E.g., on my platform, including <stdio.h> defines int64_t.)

I don't think GCC has ever intended to be strictly standard compliant, unless it has been to justify what effects compiler optimizations can do. If your goal is not compilation but standard compliance check, then maybe you need separate static code analyzer.

Re “their answers don't seem to explain why there's no warning when using -m32”: The warning would occur on the typedef (rather than where the typedef-defined type is used), but warnings are suppressed in system header files.

@AndrewHenle Maybe for a developer that uses stdint.h as a library it doesn't matter, but I'm trying to automatically determine the C89-compliance status given any C source file and this involves some compiler frontend work like resolving all composed types to basic types... @user694733 and yes if there's no easy way with existing compilers I guess I have to write my own. I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing about current compilers...

@EricPostpischil But I didn't find any #pragma that suppresses warnings in clang or linux's stdint.h...

Does this answer your question? GCC options for strict C90 code?

@Harith Nope, see the last paragraph of the question and linked questions.

@R-R automatically determine the C89-compliance status given any C source Good luck with that. Per the C89 rationale: "... codifies the common, existing definition of C and which promotes the portability of user programs across C language environments."  C89 is a "least-common-denominator" language that any source existing from that era will almost certainly not strictly conform to.  Prior to C89, there was no standardization of C, and C89 was not widely adopted anyway.  C standardization didn't really happen until C99 (and never on MSVC)

@AndrewHenle Well, trying to determine the boundary of the
"least-common-denominator" can be a interesting thing to do. at least Lua is claimed to be implemented in "pure ANSI C"...

@R-R: There does not need to be a #pragma. Suppressing warnings in system headers is built into the compiler.

@EricPostpischil Ah, thanks! I didn't know that. Could you turn this into an answer?

"I'm trying to automatically determine the C89-compliance status given any C source file" -- I'm not aware of any C compiler that provides anything remotely resembling a complete solution to that problem.  Certainly GCC and Clang do not.  Their -std= options are primarily about assumptions that the source being compiled  may safely make, not about making non-conflicting extensions unavailable or forbidding programs from relying on such extensions.


The most relevant question on SO seems to be this and this, but their answers don't seem to explain why there's no warning when using -m32.

GCC would issue a warning on the typedef (rather than where the defined type is used), but GCC has built-in behavior to suppress warnings in system headers. So does Clang.
A potential workaround is to make your own versions of system headers that suppress the undesired type definitions. For each standard header, make a file with this template:
#define int64_t  DoNotUseint64_t
#define uint64_t DoNotUseuint64_t
#include <absolute path to actual system header>
#undef  uint64_t
#undef  int64_t

Put those files in a directory, and compile with -isystem ThatDirectory.
(Note you must do this for each standard header, because standard headers are allowed to include and define others even if the C standard does not explicitly say so. E.g., on my platform, including <stdio.h> defines int64_t.)
This will result in no typedef being made for int64_t (it will be made for DoNotUseint64_t instead), so your program will get a compiler error if it attempts to use int64_t. There is some chance these redefinitions will  break something in the standard headers, but you will have to try it and see.
As Lundin notes, you could use #pragma GCC poison int64_t to flag uses of int64_t and other types. Some consideration of this versus the #define method above:

You need to edit the sources to insert the #pragma after all standard headers are included. (A problem arises if these inclusions are anywhere other than the beginning of the source file, as you need to poison the identifiers for the user source code and not for the standard headers.)
A strictly conforming C 1990 program may use int64_t and other such identifiers provided it defines them itself, since these were ordinary identifiers in C 1990. If that is an issue for you, then the #define method above allows that to work, whereas the poison method does not.


The code is still strictly conforming. A compiler or application is allowed to have headers of the #include <header.h> flavour even though they are not part of the standard lib. Given that nothing in those headers conflicts with a strictly conforming program. They may contain custom types. The identifiers int64_t etc do not conflict with anything in a strictly conforming C89 implementation.
What header.h (in this case stdint.h) does internally in the corresponding implementation file is none of the compiler's business, unless the compiler is tasked with compiling that code too, which isn't a requirement. The library will have to provide an interface in C though the header file, but from there the implementation of the actual library can be delivered in some lib or object file format. Which in turn need not even be written in C.
long long however isn't valid in C89, because long is a reserved keyword so some 3rd party header can't provide an identifier like that.
Compiling with gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors gives:

error: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]

clang:

error: 'long long' is an extension when C99 mode is not enabled [-Werror,-Wlong-long]

As for -m32, that's irrelevant for standard conformance. As long as long is at least 32 bits, it is conforming. 32 bit applications may of course support 64 bit types too, even though the CPU isn't capable of munching those in a single instruction.
If you still insist on blocking int64_t from compiling for whatever reason, you could add something like:
#pragma GCC poison int64_t


Thanks for the info. But -m32 is actually relevant here because int64_t expands to long long in this case, and the compiler issue no warning, which means compiler treats the system header and my own header unequally.

@R-R It appears to have no effect on int64_t and it would be weird if it did.

@R-R which means compiler treats the system header and my own header unequally  System headers are part of the implementation.  They will be treated differently.

@AndrewHenle And this inequality even overrides -std=c89 -pedantic on the command line and there's no flag to suppress it? I thought user-instructions have the highest priority... Anyway, I guess this is then more of a design choice of the language and compilers...

Re “The code is still strictly conforming”: C 1990 4 says “A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard…” <stdint.h> and int64_t are not specified in the 1990 standard, so OP’s test.c is not a strictly conforming program as specified by C 1990. Re “A compiler or application is allowed to have headers of the #include <header.h> flavour even though they are not part of the standard lib”: Yes, a conforming implementation may have that. Programs that use them are not strictly conforming.

@EricPostpischil As far as the C89 compiler knows, that's an application header. If we can't declare application headers, then we wouldn't be able to write meaningful programs. #include <header.h> is defined by C89 6.8.2, although which location it boils down to is of course implementation-defined, same thing with standard headers like #include <stdio.h>. The <header.h> syntax is not implementation-defined.

@Lundin: Re “If we can't declare application headers, then we wouldn't be able to write meaningful programs”: As I have written numerous times in various places in Stack Overflow, strictly conforming programs are quite limited, largely just text interactions and abstract mathematical calculations. Nonetheless, that is what strictly conforming means. OP’s program is not strictly conforming. Re “As far as the C89 compiler knows, that's an application header”: What the compiler knows is not relevant. The program uses something not defined in the standard, so it is not strictly conforming.

@R-R You are trying to pedantically apply an ancient, out-of-date standard literally from the last century and that was never widely nor strictly adhered to by anyone.

@EricPostpischil So you are saying that the #include directive is not defined by ISO C or otherwise not a feature of the ISO 9899:1990 language. Ok. And you are of course aware that your personal interpretation is not at all in line with the C rationale 5.10? "A strictly conforming program is another term for a maximally portable program. The goal is to give the programmer a fighting chance to make powerful C programs that are also highly portable, without seeming to demean perfectly useful C programs that happen not to be portable, thus the adverb strictly."

@EricPostpischil "strictly conforming programs are quite limited" doesn't quite add up with "powerful C programs that are also highly portable", now does it?

No, the #include directive is specified by C 1990. Including system headers is specified by C 1990. Using a feature that a system header might provide in one C implementation but that is not specified by C 1990 is not strictly conforming. My interpretation is precisely in line with the rationale. OP’s program is not maximally portable because it will not work in a C 1990 implementation that does not provide <stdint.h> or that does not provide int64_t.

Re "strictly conforming programs are quite limited" doesn't quite add up with "powerful C programs that are also highly portable", now does it?”: Yes, it does line up. Strictly conforming programs are quite limited: They cannot use graphics. They cannot use operating system routines. They cannot depend on particular ranges of integer or floating-point types. They cannot depend on the character set. They may be powerful by expectations in 1990, but they are quite limited.

In any case, the text in the standard is clear. “A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard…” OP’s program makes use of a feature not specified in the standard.

@EricPostpischil And yet it does not say anywhere that <header.h> must be provided as part of the implementation. A real world examples would be <pthread.h> which may as well be provided as a 3rd party lib separately installed, as is done on some Windows compilers for example.

Although I'm sympathetic to the idea that stdint.h could be considered an application header, in the end, I don't think it flies.  If the program relies on the system to provide that header then it is not an application header.  I think a careful interpretation of the spec must find that the same applies to third-party libraries not bundled, in source form, with the program being considered.  The only workable dividing line is between whether it is provided by the program for itself, or whether the program relies on the C implementation and host environment (if any) to provide it.

@Lundin: Re “And yet it does not say anywhere that <header.h> must be provided as part of the implementation”: Do you mean it does not say that the standard library headers must be provided or that it does not say that any other headers to be included via the <…> form must be provided? Regarding the former, the standard certainly does require that an implementation provide the headers specified in clause 7. Regarding the latter, what is your point? An implementation may or may not provide other headers. Using them renders a program not strictly conforming.
